# Internal server error from AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a `ul` that consists of `li`s which are sortable i.e drag and droppable, I put the ids in an array and try to send to my controller through AJAX but it keeps on saying `Internal server error` please what may be the problem

This is my HTML

```
@if(isset($images_ext)&& !empty($images_ext))
      <ul class="reorder1 row">
                                @foreach ($images_ext as $image)
                                    <li class="img-box" data-src="{{$image->filename}}" id="{{$image->id}}">
                                        <div class="img-w" style="background-image: url('{{$image->filename}}')">
                                            {{-- <a href=""> <img class="mb-2 uploaded-photos " src="{{$image->filename}}" alt=""></a>!--}}
                                        </div>
                                        <span style="color: #333333;position: relative;width: 100%;text-align: justify;
         display: inline;">{{$image->description}} <i class="fa fa-upload" style="margin-left: 10px; color:#333333;"></i></span>
                                    </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        @endif
```

This is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                       url: "{{ action('ImageController@update') }}",
                        data: {ids: " " + h + ""},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function () {
                            console.log(h);
                        }
                    });
```

This is my Route

```
Route::post('/settings/orderphotos', 'ImageController@update')->name('settings.updatephotos');
```

This is my controller

```
 public function update(Request $request){
    $data = [];
      $count = 1;
        // Get images id and generate ids array
        $id_array = $request->ids;
        $data["success"]= $id_array;
     //   dd($id_array);
        foreach ($id_array as $id) {
            $image = Image::findOrFail($id);
            $image->update([
                'image_order' => $count
            ]);
            $count++;



        }
    return json_encode('status', 'Image order saved');

}
```

Comment: Its because your backend code is expecting an array whereas you are sending it in string form. To better understand the problem, open your network tab, clear it and then make the call. You will be able to see what error, backend is throwing.

Comment: OK @yousaf how should I then send it, please give an example

Comment: data: {ids: " " + h + ""}, If variable `h` contains the array then why are you wrapping it with "". Just do it like data: {ids: h}

Comment: Still not working @Yousaf

Comment: Check your network tab and paste the data parameter here. The parameters that are send to the backend (would be in the header tab inside network when you select the call)

Comment: @YousafHassan  This is the error message, json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given, it's a 500 internal server error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your json_encode() function call. You are using it wrong.
If you want to send status back to the client, do it this way.
Replace

```
return json_encode('status', 'Image order saved');
```

with this code

```
$response = ['status' => 'Image order saved'];
return json_encode($response);
```